# Tor not starting at system boot

Tags: ssh, startup, tor

I just installed a .onion address forwarded to a local ssh server so I could access my files over multiple network types. Usually when I install Tor it auto starts with my computer. I actually have to go in and kill it from time to time because it causes problems. Now that I've setup my onion address, I'm having to start Tor every time I log in from command line. How do I get tor to start with the system as usual and not just my individual user account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple upstart script like this (adapted from Fedora's tor-upstart package):

```
start on runlevel [345] and starting local
stop  on runlevel [!345]

limit nofile 4096 4096

respawn
exec /usr/bin/tor --runasdaemon 0 --quiet
```

Just save that in `/etc/init/tor.conf` and run `sudo start tor`. It should then start on the next boot. if it doesn't, it'll log to `/var/log/upstart/tor.log`

Comment: I talked to the tor community about it. I had an onion address pointing to my system (in my home folder). Basically, Tor would start every time, realize it didn't have ownership of my onion address and then kill itself. I had to give ownership of my onion directory to debian-tor.